# Check if a generic type is an array

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I can't understand why for the last line the generic type is converted from `[{Constructor1: typeof Constructor1}, {Constructor2: typeof Constructor2}]` to `RunnerTokensMap`.
As a consequence, after conversions, the type is at the same time an array and is not an array.

```
type Constructor<T extends {} = {}, A extends any[] = any[]> = new (...args: A) => T;
type ConstructorsWithTokens = Record<string, Constructor>;
type ConstructorsWithTokensMap = ConstructorsWithTokens | Array<ConstructorsWithTokens>;
type ConstructorByToken<C extends ConstructorsWithTokensMap, T extends string | Constructor> = 
        C extends Array<any> ? 1 : 2;

export function getByToken<
    C extends ConstructorsWithTokensMap,
    T extends string,
>(construct: C, token: T): ConstructorByToken<C, T> {
    return null as any;
}

class Constructor1 { method1(): void {} }
class Constructor2 { method2(): void {} }

let constructor1 = getByToken([{Constructor1}], 'Constrructor1') // Type: "1" OK!;
let constructor2 = getByToken([{Constructor1, Constructor2}], 'Constrructor1') // Type: "1" OK!;
let constructor3 = getByToken([{Constructor1}, {Constructor2}], 'Constrructor1') // Type: "1 | 2" Not OK!;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqUEAHsBAgCZJQDeAvlALx30A0UAgsWRdVAEMEIANoBdZoOHiAfJIQQA7lAAUAOg0DUAcyQAuLgEpmcggG4AUKEixEKDNlxIA6gEtgACwJwA1hRosAEoQmLiUePauCNoc8MhoWDioMpbW0HH2iU5unt5+yACyAmCSGQmOqC7uXr7+UAA+XKioAiB4ZQ5JVbm1yClW4Ol25UkAQiB5FO085FQ0HVmVOTX5SEVgHESks-yR0Q228Z24ciwWUBeXFzAzfDScza14QiByAPxQAIxQBgBMlhZSGBcMAoAAzdAIbCuRBQbQQYDjSYIPDnS43bZ3Q6ZCrdFb+dZsNEXLa8OZQPYxCwyFShI6JAwwDg4fIGAiGRnDY6oJG9dqbOS0YlQVAI9CoBBQBDoAA2MsENBelnoFgsmBlAiQ8y5i2+tCgAFsER44JRPioOVAAG5wVyUVhQFXqzXa+kVX50Q3G02-C0GG12h0qiwyhFQOk4pLfFjwxETXoqES0BYVT70MQcADkHW5n0zxgA9AWoARBgYAESfctQADyAGkAISWUOgiMjXAemMI3n5RPJnWp2IDpK-dNZnO6-NQIslstQSvV+tNkNhtvcgDMkljPYofZTUfYdH3HbHUGzXNzU5npcgFe+jV+1YAcnBQUvLEA)

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179 . TS often infers arrays of unions as opposed to tuples in the absence of annotations

Comment: I can't get to a real computer to answer this but I think the problem is that the literal `[{Constructor1}, {Constructor2}]` is inferred to be an array of a union where one key is a `Constructor` and the other is `undefined`.  If you change `type ConstructorsWithTokens = Record<string, Constructor | undefined>` you might have more luck.

Comment: @jcalz If adding `undefined` it actually worked, but I don't understand the magic (how does it work?) And how to avoid `undefined` in `ConstructorsWithTokens`?

Comment: It has to do with how your array literal is inferred; if you want it to work with your types as written then you need to do something like `[{ Constructor1 } as ConstructorsWithTokens, { Constructor2 }]` to stop the compiler from caring that the first element has no `Constructor2` key and the first has no `Constructor1` key.  I don't know why you care about `| undefined` though, since any `Record<string, XXX>` is more accurately described as `Record<string, XXX | undefined>` (unless it really has properties at every possible key).  I will write up an answer when I get a chance

Comment: @jcalz I understood what `undefined` is for. I wanted to avoid `| undefined`, so that with further extraction I would not get `Constructor1 | undefined`. But I realized that I can just filter `undefined` using a unary condition in `ConstructorByToken`. Thanks!